# Security Review for 3rd party .net web app integrating with Quickbooks via the Quicbooks API - What pages must use SSL?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Apparently, when publishing a .net web app for consumption by QuickBooks users, the app must undergo a security review.  One of the requirements is with regard to use SSL when communicating between the .net web app and Intuit.

My question is, does the WHOLE web site need to be using SSL/https, or just those pages that give the user access to Intuit via the QuickBooks API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS Settings - HTTPS is enforced on all pages of your application.

Ref Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0040_publishing_your_app/0030_passing_the_security_review#Application_Server_Configuration

Thanks